# Postgres ltree support using sails.js

Tags: postgresql, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I am trying to use sails.js to build a project and am having trouble, I want to patch the "types" that get passed to the waterline postgres adapter so I can use the postgres type.

I have a fork of the current postgres adapter, and when I change waterline support for types to include ltree the adapter works.

This is the fork of the postgres adapter
https://github.com/opus-1/sails-postgresql

And here is the code I want to monkey patch:

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/lib/waterline/utils/types.js

```
module.exports = [
  'string',
  'text',
  'integer',
  'float',
  'date',
  'time',
  'datetime',
  'boolean',
  'binary',
  'array',
  'json',
  'mediumtext',
  'longtext',
  'objectid'
];
```